# Longest Collatz sequence using dynamic programming in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge, collatz-sequence

I'm not getting where else should I optimize it. Is there any way to optimize this code any further? Just give me hints.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static int[] countarray = new int[5000000]; //for memoization
    static int count; //for calculating length
    public static void main(String[] args){
        countarray[0]=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scan.nextInt(); //number of inputs
        while(t > 0){
            int num = scan.nextInt(); // number upto which we have to find maximum length of the sequence
            int max = 0; 
            int result = 1; 
            while(num >= 1){
                    count = 0;
                    if(countarray[num-1] != 0)
                        count = countarray[num-1];
                    else
                        counter(num);
                    if(count > max){
                        max = count;
                        result = num;
                    }
                    num--;
            }
            t--;
            System.out.println(result);    
        }

    }
    public static int counter(int temp){
        if(temp <= 1)
            return count;
        if(temp < 5000000 && countarray[temp-1] != 0){
            count += countarray[temp-1];
            return count;
        }
        if(temp % 2 == 0)
            counter(temp/2);
        else
            counter((3 * temp) + 1);
        count++;
        if(temp < 5000000){
            countarray[temp-1] = count;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: the if(temp<=1) statement won't be reached, since you are checking the number before you call the function counter.

Comment: Yeah! but it can be reached through recursion line i.e., counter(temp/2) @AngelaPan

Comment: oops,you are right!! didn't see that.

Comment: @AngelaPan Please, suggest any thing so that I could optimize this. :'(

Comment: You should probably only post the relevant code.  There is some kerfuffle about the input which is quite confusing.

Comment: Your performance problem is likely due to the fact that `counter` is recursive.   You should run a loop instead.

Comment: Okay! I'm going to edit it. Adding some comments would be a better option I think.

Comment: @toto2  Using a loop will make it more complex I think. As, recursion is computing all other counts for other numbers as well.

Comment: I like recursion too, but it has a massive cost. The compilers of some languages can  sometimes transform recursions to loops, but not Java.

Comment: @toto2 I used iteration instead. Guess what? Same TLE .

Comment: Any specific reason for the 5000000? My guess is this is part of the assignment. If the assignment specifies a lower "max" input number you should decrease this so you don't spend time calculating unneeded results as well.

Comment: @Imus It's the part of the constraints provided 1<= n<= 5000000

Comment: do you mind sharing the URL of the question, so we can try? thanks.

Comment: @AngelaPan Yeah Sure! Here it's https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler014 I have already solved it using above code. I'm just trying to find optimization for some test cases with higher no. of inputs.

Comment: ohh so you are not getting TLE?

Comment: I'm getting TLE for higher no. of inputs. That't what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You memoized once, but you needed to do it twice

Suppose you started with the entire `countarray` filled in for free.  Your program would still time out because you have \$10^4\$ test cases, and for each test case, you are searching up to \$5*10^6\$ array entries for a total of \$5*10^{10}\$ operations.  In other words, your program runs in \$O(T*N)\$ time, which is too slow.

Think about what happens when the first test case is 5000000 and the second test case is 4999999.  When you found the answer for the first test case, you should have also found the answer for the second test case.  But you 
didn't memoize that anywhere.  If you just did a pass where you found the answer for each `n` once and saved the answers in a second memoization array, then each test case would take \$O(1)\$ time.  Then your total time would be \$O(T + N)\$, which is \$O(N)\$ to build the answer array and \$O(T)\$ to handle \$T\$ test cases.

#### Be careful of overflow

When computing the collatz sequence, it is easy to overflow a 32-bit integer.  I would recommend using a `long` instead of an `int`.  You might be overflowing and not knowing it because the `if (temp <= 1)` check may be cutting the sequence short.

Comment: After seeing the hackerrank link and the huge number of test cases this answer is indeed the obvious solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only posted this to get advice on performance, but I will nonetheless give you a short code review because your code is very sloppy (not the actual logic, but cleanliness / readability).

The whole block of code `while (num >= 1)` should be made a function called maybe `solve` instead of just being some code within the main method.

Java naming convention would use instead `countArray`.

I would personally have kept the natural index as the key in `countarray`, meaning `countarray[num]` is the count for `num` instead of having to call `countarray[num - 1]` everywhere.  Of course, `countarray` would be of size `num + 1` and `countarray[0]` is meaningless.

Try to label all `final` member variables as such.  So here `countarray` is `final`.  Most new languages have that all variables are immutable (aka final) by default, unless otherwise specified.  It's easier to reason about code when you who most things can't change.

Java has the syntax `5_000_000`.  I actually had to count the zeros because I was not sure if it was 500,000 or 5,000,000.

You should have defined something like `private static final int CACHE_SIZE = 5_000_000` and use that throughout your code.  Now you have `5000000` hard coded everywhere which makes it awkward if you want to modify it.  Also maybe in one place you could mistakenly write `500000`.

I don't like too much that `count` is static (of course `countarray` should be static).  But I guess you had no choice since you used a functional style instead of an object-oriented style so you only have static methods.  But you can look what others did submitting this very same problem for review on this site (see "Related" on the right of this page).  Functional style is probably better for this task, but it's not quite the Java way.  That would have been more appropriate for example in Kotlin.

---

On a different note, related to some comments above, I did some search and it does seem that now the JVM can sometimes inline some recursive.  I was glad to see that since it can make big performance improvements.  Nevertheless, you should keep in mind that it probably won't inline all recursive functions and you might sometimes performance penalty using recursion.

Also, did you figure out how to get better performance?  Many people posted reviews for the exact same problem (see "Related" on the right of this page) and they have pretty much the same solution as you and no one seemed to have performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: see JS1's answer for the biggest efficiency gain. I'll leave this answer here for some minor improvements in case you want to squeeze out more efficiency at the cost of readability.

- remove the recursion.
- After an increase step (number was odd), you already know it's even (since 3*odd is still odd and +1 makes it even). So you can skip some checks.
- Use bitwise operators for slightly faster even check and to divide by 2.

main algorithm could look something like this:

```
for(int i = 2; i < maxStoredIndex; i++){
    int count = 0;
    int n = i;
    while(n>=i){ //n not in previously calculated results
        if(n&1 == 0){ // n even
            n >>= 1; // n /= 2
            count++;
        } else {
            n = (3*n + 1)/2;
            count+=2;
        }
   }
   count+= previously calculated result; //since n < i we know this exists
   store result for i
}
```

I didn't check how much faster this would be, and you still need to fill in the parts like storing/fetching previous results. But this should give you the main idea on how to speed up filling in the cashe.

Comment: `after an increase step, you know it's even` is not true: 20 divided by 2 is 10 and then 10 * 3 + 1 = 31 which is not even.

Comment: but 10 is not an "increase step". By increase step I mean when `n` is odd. Since 3*odd is still odd, and +1 makes it even.

Comment: 10 isn't odd although. So why would I put it in the condition for odd? @toto2

Comment: 10/2=5 ... That looks like a natural number to me, so 10 does seem to be even.

Comment: It was by mistake @Imus

Comment: Editted my answer to make this point more clear. (And I also don't think it's THAT much of an improvement after looking at it again).

Comment: @Imus shouldn't it be if(n&1 == 0) for even ?

Comment: That is entirely correct :) My mistake.

Comment: The only thing that bitwise operations instead of division by 2 are good for is producing gibberish code.

Comment: @kraskevich I wouldn't use these myself in production code if readability was the main concern (which is almost always the case). But here the issue was performance. If at some point you find that a method works but should be faster (after you find out that it's the bottleneck) then that is the only time I look into bit-wizardry to speed things up.

Comment: postulating that a removal of recurstion would be the biggest optimization is flat-out wrong. The correct optimization for this challenge is to correct the memoization code so it's most effectively used. Adding bitwise shifting and evenness-checks should generally be compiler-optimized already, if not, it's still weird to bitshift the even case, but not the second step of the odd case.

Comment: @Vogel612 you are entirely correct that the double memoization is the solution to the hackerrank problem. But that's only clear after reading that problem. Not from the question here. My answer was to optimise finding the maximum colatz sequence up to a given input. (Quick note: not all compilers optimise the division by 2 to bitshifts). Now that we know that there can be a huge amount of inputs as well, it becomes obvious that you want to memoise those too, just like I said in a comment on JS1's answer.